# Postgrest api - Отбор по в массиве jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Есть таблица

```
users
- name text
- objects jsonb

name     objects
alik     [2,3,4]
tolik    [45,78,34]
katy     [2,4,6]
```

Использую postgrest api, нужно получить только те записи у которых значение в массиве jsonb совпадает с 2

```
query = "/users?objects@>[2]";
```

выдает все записи, а нужно

```
name     objects
alik     [2,3,4]
katy     [2,4,6]
```

также есть таблица types

```
name -text     objects - jsonb
tapok           [{"id":1, "total":10},{"id":2, "total":50},{"id":3, "total":10}]
shot           [{"id":5, "total":10},{"id":7, "total":50},{"id":2, "total":10}]
body           [{"id":3, "total":10},{"id":2, "total":50},{"id":1, "total":10}]
```

Как правильно записать запрос с отбором по id в колонке objects?

```
const id = 2;
query = "/types?objects->>id=eq."+id";
```

неработает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала обязательное предупреждение, что если у вас часто
возникает надобность в подобных операциях, то лучше нормализовать схему
далее.

Вы не указали версию.  В *PostgreSQL* версии **12** и позже
можно воспользоваться запросом *SQL/JSON Path*:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM users
 WHERE objects @? '$[*] ? (@ == 2)'
;
```

---

Так как у вас *PostgREST*, а он не поддерживает синтаксис
*SQL/JSON Path*, вам придётся использовать несовместимый язык из
предыдущих версий *PostgreSQL*:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM users
 WHERE objects @> CAST('[2]' AS JSONB)
;
```

Если судить по документации, это у вам будет что-то типа:

```
/users?objects=cs.{2}
```

Comment: Ainar-G Спасибо! Да, прямой запрос отрабатывает правильно. Но я использую postgrest и тут все печально...
http://postgrest.org/

Comment: @ВиталяПалкин  Попробуйте то, чем я дополнил ответ.

Comment: /users?objects=cs.2
Вот отработало правильно, в случае если objects содержит массив [1,2,3].
Если objects содержит [{"id":3, "total":10},{"id":2, "total":50},{"id":1, "total":10}].
пытаюсь сделать запрос в виде /types?objects=cs.{id,2}
выдает ошибку: invalid input syntax for type json\"}".
Ругается на скобки... но как достучаться до ключа id?)

Comment: @ВиталяПалкин  Это уже новый, более сложный вопрос, как мне кажется.

Comment: все правильно. создал новый вопрос)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1159078/postgrest-%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-jsonb