# PostgREST Отбор по значению ключа в массиве jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

psql (PostgreSQL) 11.7

Есть таблица types

```
name -text     objects - jsonb
tapok           [{"id":1, "total":10},{"id":2, "total":50},{"id":3, "total":10}]
shot           [{"id":5, "total":10},{"id":7, "total":50},{"id":2, "total":10}]
body           [{"id":3, "total":10},{"id":2, "total":50},{"id":1, "total":10}]
```

Нужно отобрать все строки в таблице, с отбором в колонке objects по значению id

Пробывал

```
/types?select=name&objects->0->>id=eq.1
```

выводит только одну строку, все потому что в запросе указывается номер строки в массиве objects
/types?select=name&objects->[Номер Строки]->>id=eq.1

```
name
tapok
```

а нужно

```
name
tapok 
body
```

Как можно переделать запрос, для вывода всех строк где id = 1?

Comment: Попробуйте `/users?objects=cs.[{"id":1}]::jsonb`?

Comment: /users?objects=cs.[{"id":1}]::jsonb
/users?objects=cs.[{id:1}]::jsonb
/users?objects=cs.{id:1}::jsonb
/users?objects=cs.{id.1}::jsonb
"response":{"statusCode":400,"body":{"hint":null,"details":"Token \"id\" is invalid.","code":"22P02","message":"invalid input syntax for type json"}

Comment: пробывал и с ковычками и без, везде одна и таже ошибка.

Comment: наверное придется отказаться от postgrest и использовать прямые запросы к бд. 
на элементарных вещах приходиться плясать с бубном вокруг этого postgresta =)

Comment: Это тоже хорошее решение.

Comment: Решил проблему написание функции в postgresql, чтоб не переделывать весь код на прямые запросы